# @font-face changes only one letter

Tags: html, css, font-face, font-family

The problem is that when I use @font-face it changes only a single letter (A), and its suppose to change all letters.

I believe I am linking the font correctly, I can see its loaded in the sources.

Same happens in Chrome, Firefox, IE and on mobile

Any ideas whats the issue?

```
@font-face {
  font-family:"MIROSLN";
  src:url("MIROSLN.eot?") format("eot"),
  url("MIROSLN.woff") format("woff"),
  url("MIROSLN.ttf") format("truetype"),
  url("MIROSLN.svg#MiroslavNormal") format("svg");
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, .navbar-brand, 
.page-scroll, .intro-lead-in, 
.intro-heading, .btn , 
.section-heading,
.nav-tabs a
{
  font-family: "MIROSLN"; 
}
```

[Here is link to the page:](http://web-lom.com/manastir/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80.html)

[image: And screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The font you are loading is *not* a Unicode font. It is one of those old-school fonts which assign Cyrillic shapes to Latin letters. Try to replace, for example, "Закуска" with "Zakuska" in the HTML source.

In this day and age you should find a font which uses the correct encoding for the Cyrillic letters. If you *must* use that font, look at it with Character Map or a similar application and write the text using its one-of-a-kind encoding.

Comment: I did not know that. Works exactly as you said. 
I will look for font with the correct encoding, I don't have to use that one.
  
Thank you very much!!!